# When TLS1.0 disabled on Server 2012 R2 Giving error to client browser as "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally"

Tags: https, tls1.1, tls1.0

I did following things on Server 2012 R2 :
 -> Disabled TLS 1.0 
 -> To enable TLS 1.1 . Application Pool changed to ".NET  CLR Version v4.0.30319" Which wAS earlier "V2.50727"
 -> In code TLS 1.1 is enabled as :- ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 ;

When i run application locally i.e. on localhost it works fine using 'http' as well as 'https'.
But when i run application from another machines browser ,it works fine with 'http' but for https giving error as "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally".

To resolve this , i did debugging ..
Following is code from where receving error..

```
try
{
var httpOb = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0");
httpOb.open("POST","test.aspx", false);
httpOb.send(request);
}
catch(e)
{
alert(e.message);
return "";
}
```

In above code ,When send() method gets called,Exception occures and alert shows with message "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally".

Please suggest what settngs or code change is requried... I am using Windows 2012 R2 Server ,IIS 8.5 ver

Thanx..
Sambhaji.